# scale mouse coordinates on document relative to HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML5 canvas of a certain size on the page

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
```

Right now, the canvas is painted when the mouse is dragged over it (i.e. you click first(not necessarily inside the canvas) then start dragging the mouse over it without releasing) Script below;

```
  $(function () {
  var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = c.getContext("2d");
  var clickX = new Array();
  var clickY = new Array();
  var clickDrag = new Array();
  var paint;
  var $canvas=$("#canvas");

  $(this).mousedown(function (e) {         

      paint = true;
      addClick(e.pageX - $canvas[0].offsetLeft, e.pageY - $canvas[0].offsetTop);
      redraw();
  });


  $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
      if (paint) {
          addClick(e.pageX - $canvas[0].offsetLeft, e.pageY - $canvas[0].offsetTop, true);
          redraw();
      }
  });

  $(this).mouseup(function (e) {
      paint = false;
  });

  $(this).mouseleave(function (e) {
      paint = false;
  });

  function addClick(x, y, dragging) {
      clickX.push(x);
      clickY.push(y);
      clickDrag.push(dragging);
  }

  function redraw() {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clears the canvas

      context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
      context.lineJoin = "round";
      context.lineWidth = 2;

      for (var i = 0; i < clickX.length; i++) {
          context.beginPath();
          if (clickDrag[i] && i) {
              context.moveTo(clickX[i - 1], clickY[i - 1]);
          } else {
              context.moveTo(clickX[i] - 1, clickY[i]);
          }
          context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
          context.closePath();
          context.stroke();
      }
  }

});
```

What I need now is a way to scale all the mouse coordinates on document during the document's mouse events  to the relative coordinates inside the canvas.

so that no matter wherever you drag the mouse on the document it is drawn inside the canvas (in relatively small size of course). Any Idea how to achieve this?

**http://jsfiddle.net/umwc5/3/**

**Why I need this?**

It is for a signature application, When a user scribbles the signature using a tablet on a page(without seeing  the page!) the entire signature is to be registered in a small canvas.

**Update**

**[The final working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umwc5/6/)**

Comment: You'd have to calculate the page mouse coordinates like you would on any page, find the offset of the canvas on the page, then calculate a kind of pseudo canvas-mouseposition from there. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "relatively small size" on the canvas when you're not directly over the canvas

Comment: `No matter wherever you drag the mouse on the document it is drawn inside the canvas.` --> that must not be the proper way to do it, since `canvas drawing` is much like `paint`ing , you must allow the user to draw only if he is dragging the mouse inside the `canvas area` .

Comment: @Zeaklous, I tried to find the relative coordinates using `e.pageX - $canvas[0].offsetLeft, e.pageY - $canvas[0].offsetTop` but that logic came out wrong! It is for a signature application, so that when user scribbles the signature on a tablet it the entire signature is registered in a small canvas

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I have updated the question with the reason of why I want it to behave that way

Comment: Offsets are a bit finicky, it takes a lot of playing with different types of offsets and trial and error to get it correct. And why not just make the canvas bigger so it's easy to put the signature?

Comment: @Zeaklous If only I could :( , but the canvas has to remain small/atleast of medium size, like a preview.

Comment: I suppose I don't understand where a user is signing that is then transcribed to the canvas. Any chance you can post a rough picture of what you desire?

Comment: @Zeaklous now I can't post a picture, will do when I can. well, the problem is 70% of what I scribble on the tablet is within the canvas, but there is that remaining 30% that is left. and I have already spread the canvas way too much than what was asked of me ;) and the user doesn't see the screen while signing (the huge problem), so there is no way the user will be able to sign within the canvas perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing you were missing here was to multiply by the canvas/screen ratio.

First calculate the ratio:

```
  var docToCanv = Math.min($canvas[0].width / $('body').width(), $canvas[0].height/$('body').height());
```

Then use it like this:

```
addClick(e.pageX*docToCanv, e.pageY*docToCanv);
```

Depending on the additional behavior you want, you may need to adjust the location a bit, but this should get you past the current issue you are having.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/umwc5/4/)

Comment: yes, that was the logic I was looking for, I guess If I set the canvas width and height proportional to that of document's I will get a perfect miniature replica of the document coordinates inside the canvas right?

Comment: Yes - that is correct, though you may want to use window.  If the document contains more than displays in the browser window the user will only be drawing on the relative portion of the canvas that is visible in the browser window.  Depending on the UX you want, you can do things like starting canvas left where the user first drops their pen, etc.  You may also need to cancel the default action when the user is drawing so the user doesn't also select other elements in the document as they are drawing as it does in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umwc5/10/).